# How to install GTK3 and minGW on Windows using MSYS2

Tags: windows, gtk, gtk3, msys2

I am a big fan of C and I just finished reading "C Programming Langauge 2nd Edition". I must admit it was a great book and I learned a lot of stuff. But the thing is, until now I was just making console apps, so I want to move on and create some GUI applications. I searched Google and I found that the best library for making GUI apps in C is GTK. The problem is when I went to the GTK official website I couldn't find any binary package that I can install on Windows, instead they just mentioned that the preferred way to obtain GTK+ and its dependencies in binary form for Windows is to use the MSYS2 project. And that's it. No details and nothing about the necessary packages.

So can you guys suggest a way on how to install GTK+ on Windows or at least the list of necessary packages and dependencies?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: FYI, it might be easier to learn C++ and make GUIs with Qt.

Comment: Yes. But I prefer C because it's simple and without the OOP headache

Comment: On that very same page, "MSYS2" is a link to the website that tels you how to install it.

Comment: Use: https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/#using-gtk-from-msys2-packages

Answer (score 13):

Follow the instructions here for installing MSYS2 and updating its packages:

http://msys2.github.io/

Then make sure to start MSYS2 using the "MSYS2 MinGW 32-bit" shortcut in your start menu (or mingw32.exe), which is the environment for compiling native 32-bit Windows programs.

Then install the toolchain, development tools, and GTK3:

```
pacman -S base-devel mingw-w64-i686-toolchain mingw-w64-i686-gtk3
```

Then I guess you could get started making a Makefile or a CMake project that uses GTK.  MSYS2 gives you an environment very similar to Linux so you can use the tools and tutorials from Linux.

Comment: Thank you very much  David for your quick response. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: I have the same problem, I could move forward with this post. What would be the command to run my first script gtk ?. I found this: gcc `pkg-config gtk + -3.0` --cflags hello_world, or" C: \ Users \ Jose \ Desktop \ GTK \ hello_world .c "` pkg-config gtk + -3.0` --libs, but it does not work .

Comment: I don't know, but if you ask another question and tag it "msys2" and fix your formatting and give a clear description of why you say it didn't work, then I might take a look.